# Using path paramter as value for request body

Tags: swagger, openapi, redoc

Use path parameter `petId` as field value for `id` in request body. How can we do it?

```yaml
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Swagger Petstore
  license:
    name: MIT
servers:
  - url: http://petstore.swagger.io/v1
paths:
  /pets/{petId}:
    put:
      summary: Info for a specific pet
      operationId: UpdatePetInfoById
      tags:
        - pets
      parameters:
        - name: petId
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The id of the pet to retrieve
          schema:
            type: string
      requestBody:
          description: Info about a new pet
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pet"
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Expected response to a valid request
components:
  schemas:
    Pet:
      required:
        - id
        - name
      properties:
        id: _{$request.path.petId}_
        name:
          type: string
        tag:
          type: string
```

Comment: Why would you send the same value both in the path and in the request body?

Comment: That's simple way to do but I am trying to aut0 fill this value instead asking users to put the same value in 2 places.

Comment: Have you tried? What are you facing the issues, its working or not?